# How to Remove a Runtime Error "1004" error when using range to paste a string

Tags: excel, vba

So it probably won't be a long message as there's not much to this piece of code. Basically I am creating a code that will print a string (that looks like a countifs formula) into a cell based on a condition.

All works well in the first condition, however when I get to my else statement I get a

> Run-Time Error "1004": Application defined r object defined error.

```
Sub SetCriteria()

If Sheet1.Range("E3").Value = 1 Then
Sheet8.Range("F3") = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:Tank!G1000,Dashboard!C6"
Else: Sheet8.Range("F3") = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:Tank!G1000,""*"""

End If


End Sub
```

What I want is for cell F3 to be filled with either of the two pieces of text depending on what is put in cell E3 on Sheet one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are missing the "End of Parenthesis" from your code. Try:

```
Sub SetCriteria()

If Sheet1.Range("E3").Value = 1 Then
Sheet8.Range("F3") = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:Tank!G1000,Dashboard!C6" & ")"
Else: Sheet8.Range("F3") = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:Tank!G1000,""*""" & ")"

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your formulas are missing the closing parenthesis `& ")"` in the end.
2. You should use `Range.Formula` to set a formula.
3. You should correct your `If … Else … End If` syntax like shown below.
4. You should not repeat the sheet name `Tank!` for a range. For example `Tank!G6:Tank!G1000` should be `Tank!G6:G1000`.

Finally your code should look like below:

```
Sub SetCriteria()
    If Sheet1.Range("E3").Value = 1 Then
        Sheet8.Range("F3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:G1000,Dashboard!C6" & ")"
    Else
        Sheet8.Range("F3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:G1000,""*""" & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to paste the formula as text use the following instead:

```
Sub SetCriteria()
    If Sheet1.Range("E3").Value = 1 Then
        Sheet8.Range("F3").Value = "'=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:G1000,Dashboard!C6" & ")"
    Else
        Sheet8.Range("F3").Value = "'=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:G1000,""*""" & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the formula now has to begin with a `'` to tell Excel it is a string and not a formula. Don't worry Excel will not show the `'` later.

Comment: Surely if I use .Formula it will mean the cell would work as a formula and just return the answer?

This is not what I want to do. I just want the text returned

Comment: Then you need to use `.Value` and add a `'` in the beginning of the string: `.Value = "'=COUNTIFS(Tank!G6:G1000,Dashboard!C6" & ")"` see my edited answer